# What is the difference between file and record in OS's view?

Tags: filesystems, records

In terms of general operating system concepts, what is the difference between a file and a record?

How the OS will manage them? I know what a file is and what a record is but how it is distinguished in an 
OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeap

I got the answer

A file is a collection or set of records.

Typically, In database sense, A Group of records makes a file.

A group of attributes makes a record

Comment: sorry for posting the answer directly.but i found it r8 now.thank u.please dont scold me

Answer (score 1):

These days, on Win32 and *nix at least, there is no difference. A file is just a bag of bytes to the OS, and it's left up to applications to manage and work with those bytes, either all at once or one record at a time.

The days of defining record formats and i/o sources in JCL are long gone.

Answer (score 1):

Many operating systems regard files as a sequence of undistinguished symbols. There is no notion of record. Others, mainly those with a mainframe legacy, consider files to have a fixed record length and block I/O on record boundaries.

Originally, the hierarchy arose from magnetic tape drives where a physical record break was placed between blocks on a tape and sectors on a disk for partitioning a cylinder.

Today applications impose a record structure on files and access them as though there were boundaries and do not make partial accesses. This is particularly applicable to DBMS (as [Manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/31116/manoj-doubts) points out).

The record length does not need to be a constant value, but can change within a single file. They can be implemented with either explicit or implicit record lengths in files that contains multiple record types ([.PNG](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2083) is a good example).

In a sense, even modern OS have a preferred record size in the form of pages. These are the native blocks read from and written to the media by low-level components. This structure may need to be considered for increased performance at the margin.

Answer (score 0):

The Good answer is that 1
""A collection of related fields treated as a single unit is called a record. A collection of related record treated as a single unit is called a file or a data set""